# print the • character in a different font than the main one of the document

Tags: symbols, unicode

I am typing my document with a font that does not include the bullet character, • (U+2022 in unicode).

To replace it with a font that does I tried the following:

```
\newfontfamily{\listitemi}{Arial}
\catcode`•=\active
\protected\def •{{\listitemi\char`\•}}
```

But I guess something is terribly wrong there.

This code block is based on the one presented in the [`newunicodechar`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) manual, page 2, where they show something similar for the euro symbol (€):

```
\newfontfamily{\eurofont}{⟨some font⟩}
\catcode‘€=\active
\protected\def €{{\eurofont\char‘\€}}
```

I know I can simply use the `newunicodechar` package, but I want to do it without it.

Comment: you should always provide a test file not just post fragments but probably you do not want to define the active character but rather define `\textbullet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works flawlessly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\bulletfont}{Arial}
\catcode`•=\active
\protected\def •{{\bulletfont\char`\•}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % so nothing is added

•

\end{document}
```

If I call `pdffonts` on the generated PDF file, I get

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
NVYNAY+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
```

On the other hand, `itemize` doesn't use `•` directly, but rather `\textbullet`. So just add a line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\bulletfont}{Arial}
\catcode`•=\active
\protected\def •{{\bulletfont\char`\•}}
\let\textbullet=•

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % so nothing is added

•

\begin{itemize}
\item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```